# Automatic login on facebook from my site

Tags: sdk, facebook

I am working on a web application, I am using graph API with php sdk for accessing the facebook features.
I am using facebook connect and it is working fine for login, but every time a user come to my site and get login by using the login button.

I want to make this automatic, Is there any way that when users come to my site they get logged in automatically.
How can I achieve this..
anybody help please.

thanks in advance.
Danish

Comment: If a user already authorize your app and if a user logged in to facebook,Then you can automatically login users. Otherwise you can`t.

Answer (score 2):

If the user does not explicitly authorize you to get some private data from his Facebook account (included his Facebook ID), you can not get them.

I cannot think of a way to get the Facebook ID without the authorization of the user. So no way for you to automatically log in users.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that maybe you shouldn't make it to connect automatically, some viewers of your website might not be very happy that as soon as they get there they are automatically logged in with their facebook profiles, pictures, information, etc.

Also because there could be another one's facebook already connected on the same computer, but still...

My advice would be to just leave a button to login when the user wants.